# DP tiling a 2xN tile with L shaped tiles and 2x1 tiles?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, recurrence

https://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/online-study-material/topics/dp-tiling.php

The second question in the above link requires us to fill an 2xN grid with tiles of dimension 2x1 and an L shaped tile.

My doubt is that in the recursive formula for g(n):

`g(n) = f(n-1) + h(n-1)`

Why didn't we include the case when the bottom row has n tiles, and above row has n-3 tiles? Then I can simply put a 2x1 tile horizontally in the above row and achieve the state g(n). So we would need to add another term in the above recursion. Something like -

`g(n) = f(n-1) + h(n-1) + x(n-3)`

where `f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + g(n-2) + h(n-2)` still holds.

Basically, are we not looking into the cases how we can get the state `g(n)` ? To get `g(n)` state, either we add an L-shaped tile, and look at `f(n-1)`, or we add a 2x1 tile in the bottom layer and look at `h(n-1)`, or add a 2x1 tile in the top layer and look at `x(n-3)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This case is already included, implicitly. If you introduce a name for your case, `t(n)`, then:

```
t(n) = g(n-2)
```

because if you want to fill such a weird grid with tiles, you **have** to put one tile horizontally in the leftmost place, and then you get a grid for which they already have a name.

So, if you introduce `t(n)` and its symmetric counterpart `s(n)`, then

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + t(n) + s(n)
t(n) = g(n-2)
s(n) = h(n-2)
```

This can be immediately simplified to what they have in their discussion.

Comment: How is t(n) = g(n-2), because g(n) is the case when bottom row has '1' extra tile, not '3' extra tiles.

Comment: All these functions denote the number of tilings for a certain shape. The shapes may be different but the number of tilings is the same.